# What is this flower

Tags: identification, flowers

[image: What is this flower?]
Blooms July-September in eastern Europe. Height up to 2.5m (8 feet), though this one is like 1 m only.
Looks like something from Heliopsis genus but not sure.

Comment: Yes, @Jurp is right, it is a mexican sunflower. I had two, grown from direct seeding into the ground (out of 10 seeds, only two succeeded). In my zone 7, it cant overwinter. Some claims it self-seeds, but it didn't happen next year at my place. You will have plenty of seeds in the autumn though, they are fairly large, a curvy ones 2-3 cm long. It was really liked by bees. Phenomenal aesthetics value, almost unreal color, pictures do not do justice. Enjoy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That appears to be Tithonia rotundifolia, also known as Mexican Sunflower. Note the rounded petals and similar leaves to your plant on [this photo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tithonia_rotundifolia#/media/File:Tithonia_rotundifolia,_blomhoof,_Groenkloof_NR.jpg). It's an annual in non-tropical areas but has naturalized in areas with warm winters. The species can reach the heights you've described, while the 'Torch' cultivar is smaller at only 1m or so in height and width. If you'd like more of this plant next year, you can save the seeds if you want: start them indoors in very early spring (under lights, if possible) - maybe 4-6 weeks before your typical last frost date -  and then plant out after the last frost in your area.